# I want to query connected records (left join) and put them into array-structure in PhP, how to?

Tags: php, mysql, join

almost similar like this: [PHP/mySQL - how to fetch nested rows into multidimensinal array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357122/php-mysql-how-to-fetch-nested-rows-into-multidimensinal-array)

```
SELECT products.NAME, products_prices.PRICE FROM products LEFT JOIN products_prices ON products.ID = products_prices.PROD_ID
```

this normally would result:

```
NAME,   PRICE
window, 1000
window, 1200
mouse,  1400
```

because there are two prices for `window` and there might be no prices at all. I want it to be resulted in an array:

```
$arr = array(
             array('NAME' => 'window', 'price' => array(
                                                        array('PRICE' => 1000),
                                                        array('PRICE' => 1200)
                                                       ),
             array('NAME' => 'mouse', 'price' => array(
                                                       array('PRICE' => 1400)
                                                      )
            );
```

so, the joined record(s) would be sub-arrays. Another problem there can be multiple joins, but only LEFT JOIN-s. How to do this nicely? The linked example put the joined columns to the main part, which I dont want to.

Comment: `LEFT JOINS`, multiples of them, are about as nice as it gets. The other option are `UNION`, which turns into sub-queries, which is a bit beyond my current capabilities.

Comment: what I have tried? NOTHING :D its very complicated

Comment: see my answer below. It is not complicated. But if you never try, just ask others to do it for you, it might seem complicated even next time...

Answer (score 2):

It would look like this:

```
 $dataStore = array();
 foreach ($recordSet as $record){
     $dataStore[$record['NAME']]['prices'][] = $record['PRICE'];
 }
```

This only works if you know for sure that a single product NAME can have multiple PRICES.

Answer (score 2):

```
//array you get from mysql:
$arrMysql = array(
             array('NAME' => 'window', 'PRICE' => 1000),
             array('NAME' => 'window', 'PRICE' => 1200),
             array('NAME' => 'mouse', 'PRICE' => 1400)
            );

$arr = array();
foreach ($arrMysql as $row) {
    if (isset($arr[$row['NAME']])) {
        if (isset($arr[$row['NAME']]['price'])) {
            $arr[$row['NAME']]['price'].push(array('PRICE' => $row['PRICE']));
        } else {
            $arr[$row['NAME']]['price'] = array(array('PRICE' => $arr[$row['NAME']]['PRICE']), array('PRICE' => $row['PRICE']));
            unset($arr[$row['NAME']]['PRICE']);
        }
    }
    else {
        $arr[$row['NAME']] = $row;
    }
}

//you get:

$arr = array(
             'window' => array('NAME' => 'window', 'price' => array(
                                                        array('PRICE' => 1000),
                                                        array('PRICE' => 1200)
                                                       ),
             'mouse' => array('NAME' => 'mouse', 'price' => array(
                                                       array('PRICE' => 1400)
                                                      )
            );

// and if you want your array:
$arr = array_values($arr);
```