# PHP/mySQL - how to fetch nested rows into multidimensinal array, with more foreign keys

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

well, question is like here: [PHP/mySQL - how to fetch nested rows into multidimensinal array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357122/php-mysql-how-to-fetch-nested-rows-into-multidimensinal-array)

its working (apart from adding too much columns), but what if I got more primary keys?

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't matter, the same principle holds:

```
$sql = <<<EOL
SELECT table1.pk AS pk1, table2.pk AS pk2, table3.pk AS pk3, etc...
FROM yourtable
LEFT JOIN ...
EOL;
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$data = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($data)) {
    $data[$pk1][$pk2][$pk3][etc...] = $row;
}
```

Comment: how to make this reference dynamic? I meant, sometimes "$data[$pk]", sometimes "$data[$pk1][$pk2]"