# Best practice for displaying data from two tables

Tags: php, sql

I have two tables and keep getting the same results.  The results keep giving me the deptID results "1, 2, 3" from column meetingDepts instead of "Admin, Marketing, Accounting".
These are the tables:

**Meeting**

meetingID, meetingDate, meetingDepts

**Departments**

deptID, deptName

I've created a sql statement:

```
 SELECT * FROM Meeting INNER JOIN Departments 
  ON Meeting.meetingDepts =  Departments.deptID
```

I've been through so many iterations of code that I don't have anything worth placing here.  I've searched hundreds of posts and haven't found what I'm looking for, or at least think of the right keywords to search.

I guess I'm looking for "What would you do?" as I'm out of thoughts on this. You're help is greatly appreciated.

---

I got a little bit closer today with the following code but it gives me the integers of the array.  I need to be able to output the deptName:

$meetings = explode(", ", $row_rsCurMeet['meetDepts']);
$tmp = array();
foreach ($meetings as $meeting)
$tmp[] = $meeting['deptName']; //Does not echo the name
echo implode('    ',$tmp);  // only echos the meetDepts number

Comment: What column are you using to display the department names on your page? It should be `deptName`

Comment: Aspirin...thanks for the response.  I've tried a foreach loop and only got as far as the first deptName entry.  I used the info from this post with no luck:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/357122/php-mysql-how-to-fetch-nested-rows-into-multidimensinal-array

Comment: @Torrey Shoaff, start using a SQL query tool to examine your SQL code and results. It would show you that the column `meetingDepts` contains the same number as `deptID` and that -often mentioned- `deptNames` is what you are looking for. @Jack Maney: You need quite a bit of imagination, empathy and charity in order to get the question. But it's possible ;-)

Comment: @Torrey Shoaff Your SQL might be fine, please show how are you displaying the values on the php side.

Comment: Thanks SWeko.This is as far as I've been able to get.  'code'<?php
   $teams = explode(", ", $row_rsCurMeet['meetingDepts']);
   $key = $row_rsCurMeet['deptID']; 
   $val = $row_rsCurMeet['deptName'];
   foreach ($teams as $row_rsCurMeet['deptID'] => $row_rsCurMeet['deptName']) {
   print "$val, ";
   }?>'code'    This actually prints the first deptName for the appropriate ID but it does it 3 times instead of the other teams.  Not sure if this is posted correctly...sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You should get `deptName` instead.

```
SELECT deptName
    FROM Departments
INNER JOIN Meeting ON Meeting.meetingDepts = Departments.deptID
```

The problem is that `meetingDepts` only have ids.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
SELECT deptName FROM Meeting INNER JOIN Departments ON Meeting.meetingDepts = Departments.deptID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT * FROM Meeting INNER JOIN Departments ON Meeting.meetingDepts = Departments.deptName
```

that should give you the department name.

Comment: Pretty sure `meetingDepts` contain ID's of the department names