# How to iterate over joined data in two or more nested loops?

Tags: join, loops, nested-loops

Some time ago I asked [a question about nested loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356778/php-query-single-value-per-iteration-or-fetch-all-at-start-and-retrieve-from-ar) on SO and as it was, there were queries inside the loops of my example and I got a clear answer:

> **NEVER EVER NEVER put an SQL query inside a loop**

I've tried ever since and mostly it works. Just need to make an effort and write a query that retrieves all you need at once.

BUT what do you do when you have a dataset from a JOIN query which contains nested data which you need to output in a nested way?

Example join from table A and B:

```
A.a     |  B.a     |  B.b
--------|----------|-------------
fruits  |  banana  |  yellow
fruits  |  apple   |  red
animals |  zebra   |  black&white
animals |  elefant |  gray
animals |  fox     |  red
planets |  earth   |  blue
planets |  mars    |  red
```

ok, now I got that all in an array or rowset and now I need to display something like that:

**fruits**

- yellow banana
- red apple

**animals**

- black&white zebra
- gray elefant
- red fox

**planets**

- blue earth
- red mars

it seems obvious that it should work but I've tried to wrap my mind around it several times now and I just can't come up with a solution.

At the moment I do it my old way:

```
query groups

foreach groups
{
    query animals in group
    foreach animal
}
```

but hey, NEVER EVER NEVER put sql inside a loop. so what shold I do? I do PHP but I think this is a meta question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the control break algorithm.

I'd return a result set exactly as you show in the question:

```
A.a     |  B.a     |  B.b
--------|----------|-------------
fruits  |  banana  |  yellow
fruits  |  apple   |  red
animals |  zebra   |  black&white
animals |  elefant |  gray
animals |  fox     |  red
planets |  earth   |  blue
planets |  mars    |  red
```

loop over all the rows:

- when A.a changes, output the title
- then always output the B.b + B.a value

pseudo code for application calling SQL:

```
set last_A = null
exec query

loop over result set {
    if last_A == null or fetch_A!=last_A {
        last_A=fetch_A
        display fetch_a
    }
    display fetch_Bb + fetch_Ba
    }
}//loop
```

Comment: well, I thought about something like this but I got stuck with it times again. I'll give it another try.

Comment: it totally absolutely works! had to think some more because I had to work on the B first and then display A. But that too is possible. Thanks!

Comment: this means I was just able to merge over a hundred queries into a single one :)

Answer (score 1):

If what you have is a hierarchy, a "directed acyclic graph".  SQL does not do these.

There are other graph-theory things SQL does not do.

Since SQL does not do this, the "never put SQL in a loop" rule goes out the window.

You must put the SQL in a loop for hierarchies and other graph-connection problems involving lattices and networks.

Indeed, for hierarchies, you must use recursive loops to connect all elements of the hierarchy to arbitrary depth.

If, on the other hand, you're just reformatting the query result to look like a nested hierarchy, then you're just reformatting a single SQL result set into what appears to be nested lists.

This will be one select with complex loops around the result set.  One select -- not in a loop -- and a complex loop to process one result set.

Comment: ok, I got the first part but the second part confused me. If I have exactly what I have in my example, simple 'several items per group' design where I want to loop over the groups and inside the groups over the items. then? is it possible or not?

Comment: you got to be nuts! my app displays data in grids like this all day. he basically wants to only show A.a the first time, but list B.b+B.a every time.  loop over the result set and have php build the html. you still only need one SQL result set.

Comment: Yeah, c'mon guys, confuse me :P

Comment: probably that's what he ment with the second part but he is such a professor. I mean you don't get 35'000 rep asking and answering easy questions :)

Comment: @tharkun, the solution is easy, no "complex loops" needed, only simple loops, with a simple explanation