# Zend DB relationships

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-table

I am creating an application in zend framework. Now i am stuck in the Zend table relationships.

I have 2 tables. I have set the primary key and the corresponding references in other tables.
Now i want to join the two tables using the relationships (not with the join functions). Is it possible in zend?

the tables structures are like the one below

**Schemetable**

scheme_id    ***primary key***

Scheme_name

Scheme_Desc

**Ratestable**

rate_id

Scheme_id *foreign key ref scheme_id*

rates:

Time periods:

**There is an one to many relation b/w the scheme and rates**

I have done some coding in the model classes

*Scheme.php*

```
class Scheme extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract {


 protected $_name = 'schemetable';

 protected $_dependentTables = array('rates');
}
```

*Rates.php*

```
class Rates extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract {


 protected $_name = 'ratetable';

 protected $_referenceMap = array(
   'Scheme' => array(
   'columns' => array('scheme_id'),  
   'refColumns' => array('scheme_id'), 
   'refTableClass' => 'Scheme',  
  ),
 );
}
```

How can i fetch every scheme and their corresponding rates?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why not using "(not with the join functions)" ?

Comment: You will be able to find some solution there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4433910/hand-made-queries-vs-finddependentrowset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please,
see the DOCS:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.relationships.html

**Fetching a Dependent Rowset**

> If you have a Row object as the result
>   of a query on a parent table, you can
>   fetch rows from dependent tables that
>   reference the current row. Use the
>   method:

```
$row->findDependentRowset($table);
```

> Example #4 Fetching Dependent Rowsets
>   using the Magic Method
>
> This example shows finding dependent
>   Rowsets equivalent to those in the
>   previous examples. In this case, the
>   application uses the magic method
>   invocation instead of specifying the
>   table and rule as strings.

```
  $accountsTable = new Accounts();
  $accountsRowset = $accountsTable->find(1234);
  $user1234 = $accountsRowset->current();

  // Use the default reference rule
  $bugsReportedBy = $user1234->findBugs();

  // Specify the reference rule
  $bugsAssignedTo = $user1234->findBugsByEngineer();
```

**Fetching a parent row**

> If you have a Row object as the result
>   of a query on a dependent table, you
>   can fetch the row in the parent to
>   which the dependent row refers. Use
>   the method:

```
$row->findParentRow($table);
```

> This example shows finding parent Rows
>   equivalent to those in the previous
>   examples. In this case, the
>   application uses the magic method
>   invocation instead of specifying the
>   table and rule as strings.

```
  $bugsTable = new Bugs();
  $bugsRowset = $bugsTable->fetchAll(array('bug_status = ?', 'NEW'));
  $bug1 = $bugsRowset->current();

  // Use the default reference rule
  $reporter = $bug1->findParentAccounts();

  // Specify the reference rule
  $engineer = $bug1->findParentAccountsByEngineer();
```